# how to type “smart quotes” (U+201C, U+201D)

Tags: xorg, keyboard, special-characters, unicode

It's like this: `“` (U+201C) `”` (U+201D).

Comment: Gnome?  KDE?  Any particular application?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Gnome, you would press and hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, then type <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.

Of course, that won't work in Gnome Terminal if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is bound to Copy, in which case type it in GEdit and paste it in, or learn how to enter it in your editor of choice.

Comment: You only have to hold down `ctrl+shift` while typing the `u`.  After that you can let go of `ctrl` and `shift` and type `201c` followed by a space.

Comment: @Wodin: The documentation says you have to keep holding it until the end of the numbers, but you're right, it seems to work if you let go after typing the `u`.

Comment: Would be a pain if you had to keep holding them for the whole thing :)  I'm sure I've seen documentation that mentioned my way, but I have no idea where I saw it.

Answer (score 37):

With a <kbd>Compose</kbd> key:

- <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> → `„`
- <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> → `“`
- <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> → `”`
- <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> → `‘`
- <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> → `’`

You can enter the last two characters in either order, at least in most locales. There may be locales where it only works in the order <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> works or only in the order <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd><</kbd>.

If you need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to enter some of these characters, you'll need to hold those modifiers down as usual. You can press and release <kbd>Compose</kbd> before the subsequent characters, or you can press <kbd>Compose</kbd> and keep it down, as you prefer.

Most keyboards don't have a key marked “Compose”, but you can configure one and your environment may already have one configured. On a PC, a popular choice is the “Menu” key between the right <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. The keyboard settings of most desktop environment include an option to make this key or some other key a Compose key.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. I've set the Compose key to the right Alt, but either holding it or tapping it won't make <" to “

Comment: @trVoldemort Using `Compose < "` and `Compose > "` worked for me. If it helps, I am using Linux Mint 12, running the unity shell, on a Macbook Pro, with the right option key set to `Multi_key` in my xmodmap. I reference specific hardware only in case the specific keyboard may make a difference.

Comment: @trVoldemort Are you using XIM or any similar input methods?  They tend to break usage of Compose.

Comment: Compose key combinations also depend on the locale. I like to disambiguate it by sticking my favourites in my `~/.XCompose` file.

Comment: @trVoldemort Notice that to use `Compose < "` differs from `Compose , '`.  To get the first, the `Shift` key must be held down while hitting `< "` (which might be a little awkward).

Comment: @xzhu: Were you able to figure out how this works?

Answer (score 9):

Some ‘smart’ [1] quotes without using <kbd>Compose</kbd> [2] (and without remembering Unicode codepoints):

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> = ‘

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> = ’

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> = «

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> = »

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> = “

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> = ”

These work on any desktop, provided you have `ISO_Level3_Shift` assigned to your <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key and are using a keyboard mapping like the US International Keyboard with AltGr.

For <kbd>Compose</kbd> combinations, check Gilles' answer (or the XCompose file for your locale). *They*, in turn, are dependent on your locale and/or the presence/settings of your `~/.XCompose` file.

[1] ‘Typographical’ is probably more appropriate. ‘Smart’ refers to the ability of a word processor to automatically use the correct character in a quote pair when you type the ASCII quotes `'` or `"`.

[2] You can, of course, have both <kbd>Compose</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> enabled. I do, and it works a treat.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, since I use the altgr keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

Linux Ubuntu users can type smart quotes with ...

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> / <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> ( “ / ” )

... or ...

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> / <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> ( ‘ / ’ )

Comment: wohoo, that's cool! still works, on xfce in 2022 : )

Answer (score 4):

I redefined my keyboard layout for good and I simply press alt-key + ; or ' to get: “ ”. Works in every desktop env.

There are many choices how to do it -- for example, you can use character map app (present in Gnome and KDE for sure) to get any character you want.

Comment: How exactly to map the key using character map app? I can't find this command in the app.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that runs across this: the Compose key for curly quotes didn't work for me until recently.  I'd tried it in 2-3 major distros with GNOME 2 and changing the assigned key didn't help, but when I tried with KDE 4 in SimplyMepis and set it to use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> it started working just fine.  So trying it again or switching environments, distros, or keys might be worthwhile.

Comment: I prefer to assign Control to `Caps Lock`. Compose has always worked for me, mapped to the right `Ctrl` or `Menu` keys, which closely approximates its natural location on keyboards that have it. Which key I use depends on ergonomics, because I use Compose very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

On any keyboard layout that I know of, producing these quote marks
requires using the *third level* of some keys.  This is typically
accessed by holding down the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key as a shift key.

*(I’m going to focus on typing these symbols directly, as opposed to by
using the compose key or using the “NumPad entry” method, since these
symbols are typed so often that they deserve a way to be accessed
directly.)*

Many European keyboards seem to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (`“`)
and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (`”`)

As for US keyboard, the standard US keyboard does not have these
symbols.  It only has two levels (unshifted and shifted) for
alphanumeric keys, and none of them contain these symbols.  However,
there is the “US international” variant, on which these symbols can be
accessed on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (`“`) and
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (`”`).  As you’ll see if
you try to type this, this is impressively inconvenient, as you have to
hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> with either hand, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> with the right
hand, and then either <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> with the right hand
(†1).

US International is named `us(intl)` if you use a tool like Setxkbmap:

```
setxkbmap "us(intl)"
```

†1: The French quote marks (`«»`) gets the more convenient place one
level down (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and
<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>), which is curious since I’d think that
the English curly quotes would get a more convenient placement than
them.

## More convenient typing on US International

There is an option `misc:typo` (“typo” as in “typographical”) which can
be combined with `us(intl)` since it only redefines some level 3 and 4
keys.  In particular, it maps `“` and `”` to
<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>,
respectively.  This seems much more convenient than the keys that
`us(intl)` uses.  To use this option with `us(intl)`:

```
setxkbmap -option "misc:typo" "us(intl)"
```

Another thing that can be done is to define some alternative or
additional level 3 modifiers, so that the double quotes can be typed
more comfortably.  According to [man
xkeyboard-config](https://www.mankier.com/7/xkeyboard-config#Options-Key_to_choose_5th_level),
Xkb provides quite a few ready-made options:

```
Option: Description
lv3:switch: Right Ctrl
lv3:menu_switch: Menu
lv3:win_switch: Any Win
lv3:lwin_switch: Left Win
lv3:rwin_switch: Right Win
lv3:alt_switch: Any Alt
lv3:lalt_switch: Left Alt
lv3:ralt_switch: Right Alt
lv3:ralt_switch_multikey: Right Alt; Shift+Right Alt as Compose
lv3:ralt_alt: Right Alt never chooses 3rd level
lv3:enter_switch: Enter on keypad
lv3:caps_switch: Caps Lock
lv3:bksl_switch: Backslash
lv3:lsgt_switch: <Less/Greater>
lv3:caps_switch_latch: Caps Lock; acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level chooser
lv3:bksl_switch_latch: Backslash; acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd level chooser
lv3:lsgt_switch_latch: <Less/Greater>; acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd level chooser
```

Personally I think that <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> makes for good level 3 switch:

```
setxkbmap -option "lv3:caps_switch" "us(intl)"
```

If you prefer the `misc:typo` keybindings, you can of course include
that option as well:

```
setxkbmap -option "lv3:caps_switch" -option "misc:typo" "us(intl)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alt codes <kbd>Alt</kbd>+0147 for “ and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+0148 for ”. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type the numbers that follow.